# Excel VBA - Merge rows until last row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro that will scroll through a spreadsheet an entire row at a time and merge all cells in the active row if they have data. It should do this until the last row.

The code currently sees all rows as empty and therefor skips them, I need an if condition or do until statement that will help detect and skip empty rows, detect rows with data and merge their cells and stop entirely when it reaches the last row.

My current code:

```
Sub merge()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Sheets("Body").Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Rows("1:1").Select
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "*" Then
            Selection.merge = True
            Selection.Offset(1).Select
        Else
            Selection.Offset(1).Select
        End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
sub merge2()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Sheets("Body").Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow > LastRow
    'this line below was a concept
        If ActiveCell.EntireRow & ActiveCell.Column.Value = "*" Then
            Selection.merge = True
            Selection.Offset(1).Select
        Else
            Selection.Offset(1).Select
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry! The code currently sees all rows as empty and therefor skips them, I need an if condition or do until statement that will help detect and skip empty rows, detect rows with data and merge their cells and stop entirely when it reaches the last row.

Comment: Also using `select` statements is generally dangerous and should be avoided when can. It will also only slow your code down. Also you want to merge the entire row?

Comment: If you have another suggestion, I would gladly use it. And yes, if the selected row has data, the cells of that row should be merged.

Comment: I've changed yours slightly to not use the select statements. However it is untested. Why are your merging the entire row? I'm petty sure this will only lead to issues in Excel

Comment: I am pulling the body of emails to the worksheet and without a merged cell, or with only a stretched cell, the text does not show properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested but should do what you want.

```
Option Explicit
Sub merge()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Body")

    ws.Activate

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 1 To LastRow       
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) And ws.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column > 1 Then
            ws.Rows(i & ":" & i).merge
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This `If` will test for a) whether the cell in column A is empty and b) whether there are any other cells in that row. if statement a evaluates to false AND statement b is greater than 1 it will execute the `If` statement

Comment: Strangely enough this code works, but returns an error. I get the desired effect, but on line: `ws.Rows(i & ":" & i).merge = True` I get error 438 Object doesn't support this method

Comment: Sorry josh what do you mean by 'on line: -'

Comment: Sorry, I think I can make myself more clear here. 
The code works until like `ws.Rows(i & ":" & i).merge = True` at which point it throws a runtime error.
The strange part is that this piece of the code works regardless, so when I get to that point, it merges the cells and the code stops from the error.
If I debug to it, trigger the error and then manually skip to the next line, it works.

Comment: You can suppress this message by wrapping that line with `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`. Merging the entire row will also lose any data that is not in column `A`. Is this correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought as well and it's worked, thank you. The data will be pulled into only Column A due to the code its being integrated in.

Comment: @JoshWhitfield Just thought about it. The error was being caused by having `merge = true` you don't need the true part. I've updated my code so it is just `merge` and it runs without errors

Answer (score 0):

@Tom I've taken your code and added in an error handler that makes it work without fault, thank you very much for your patience, you've been a fantastic help.

```
Sub merge2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Body")

ws.Activate

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) And ws.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column >= 1 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Rows(i & ":" & i).merge = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```